# UITableView inside Segemented Control

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I don't even know where to begin on this or if it's possible. I want to add a `UISegementedControl` to my app, but want a `UITableView` inside the `UISegmentedControl`, to display an array of photos and items.. is this possible?

It will be embedded into a `UIViewController` not a `UITableViewController`. similar to what Instagram has.

Comment: In which part Instagram uses a table inside a segmented control? Could you post an image?

Comment: You want a table view that's only about 44x44 points? That's kind of small for a table view.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7698&p=43219 this link shows what I mean.

Comment: Where in that link do you see a table view inside a segmented control?

Comment: The photos on the profile, maybe its a collection view, but how do you put it under the segmented control?

Comment: Your title and question state you want a table view *inside* a segmented control. Now you say you want the table *under* the segmented control. Please update your question and title with what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use a container view controller that has a UIPageViewController with 3 ViewController (in instagram case 'Grid', 'Table' and 'Photo Map'). On top of this container you could use a UISegmentControl or a CollectionView with a delegate for every time you select one item its child (the UIPageViewControl) switch between those 3 VCs.